# Skipping string input in java

Tags: java

I'm making a simple calculator, but I've run into a problem where a string input is skipped.
Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Calculator\n");

        while (true) {

            System.out.print("Number: ");
            float num1 = input.nextFloat();

            System.out.print("Operator: ");
            String optr = input.nextLine();

            System.out.print("Number: ");
            float num2 = input.nextFloat();


            System.out.println(num1 + num2);

        }

    }

}
```

I have tried doing `\n` but I don't know what else I should really do as I don't know what the problem is.
I know `input` is never closed, but I have tried closing it. It has no affect and I don't want to add it right now as I am making the base system.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean *exactly* by the phrase "string input is skipped"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo) After calling `input.nextFloat()` you should call `input.nextLine()`. Refer to the duplicate question for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using...

```
System.out.print("Operator: ");
String optr = input.nextLine();
```

...use this...

```
System.out.print("Operator: ");
String optr = input.next();
```

The method `nextLine()` is a bit finnicky. Long story short, if you use `nextLine()`, beware that it doesn't play well with `next()`, `nextInt()`, `nextFloat()`, etc.

If you want the long story, here is a more detailed explanation -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/13102066/10118965

Comment: [How should duplicate questions be handled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled) You may argue that the question is not a duplicate, but I believe that it is and I also believe that many people will agree with me. I would also argue that by linking to the "duplicate" question, you are basically admitting that the question is a duplicate. I think that you should refrain from answering duplicate questions.

Comment: @Abra I disagree with the way your linked post suggests duplicate questions should be answered. If there are consequences that come from that, I accept them. But I believe the solution you have linked me to is non-constructive and causes more problems than it solves.